# succeeded callback for Java SendMail Api

Tags: java, email, exception, jakarta-mail

I am using the Java MailApi and I would like to add some kind of `e-mail sent successfully` callback.

I have read [here](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html) about the `SMTPAddressSucceededException`:

> This exception is chained off a SendFailedException when the
>   mail.smtp.reportsuccess property is true.

So I have two exceptions now:

```
public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception, SMTPAddressSucceededException {
        try {
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(
                    body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));
            message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setDataHandler(handler);
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.setText(body);
            _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // Put parts in message
            message.setContent(_multipart);
            if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                        InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
            else
                message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                        new InternetAddress(recipients));
            Transport.send(message);
      } catch (SMTPAddressSucceededException e){
        Log.i("MAIL", "SMTAddressSucceededException");
      } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("MAIL", "sendMail failed");
      }
    }
  }
```

Gives the **issue**:

> There is a more general exception, 'java.lang.Exception', in the
>   throws list already

**Question**: Why is a positive callback seen as subexception of a negative one?
How can I make a difference between message sending failure and success?

Answer (score 0):

Return from the Transport.send method without an exception tells you that the message was successfully delivered to the mail server, just like the SMTPAddressSucceededException does.  The exception provides more detail, which can be useful in some cases, but if all you're looking for is an indication of success, return from the method is much simpler.  Note that neither approach tells you whether the message was successfully delivered to the recipient.